Problem with the shapekeys and driver

I'm using Rigify skeleton. I am creating a shape key to rotate the Tight_L bone along the X axis, there are no problems here. But when the hip turns outward, there is a problem. If you look at the bone, it rotates along the Y axis, which causes the problem.
Please tell me how to solve it
I have some ideas, but I do not know how to implement them in a blender.

Create shape correction keys, but you need a driver to rotate the dice along 3 axes. Is it possible to create this?

2.Lock this shape key only for the X axis, and so that the shape key does not work is equal to 0 if rotation begins along the Z and Y axes.
3.It is possible to use the SWING axis of rotation in a Blender, but I did not understand how to apply it
If someone has encountered this, share your experience of solving it

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
